# Inputting a .sas7bdat file on SAS On Demand

Tags: database, sas, sas-macro

I am using SAS Studio (the browser version) instead of a desktop SAS program.

I am trying to read a .sas7bdat file that I have uploaded onto a folder on SAS Studio.

```
    libname HW5 '~/home/xxxxxxxxxxxx/sasuser.v94/HW5';

    DATA FILE1;
          set HW5.orders;
```

RUN;

I get the error:

ERROR: File HW5.ORDERS.DATA does not exist.

NOTE: The SAS System stopped processing this step because of errors.
 WARNING: The data set WORK.FILE1 may be incomplete.  When this step was stopped there 
          were 0 observations and 0 variables.
 WARNING: Data set WORK.DISCOUNT_RET was not replaced because this step was stopped.

Here is the image of the folder:

https://ibb.co/hN83ua

I realize this is a simple error but I don't know how to fix it. Thanks! If nothing works, can i read this via infile?

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the HW5 folder in the list on the left and select `properties`. This should show you the physical location for that folder. Copy it and paste it into your LIBNAME statement enclosed in quotes.  Most likely the issue was your inclusion of the `~` in front of the path.

```
libname HW5 '/home/xxxxxxxxxxxx/sasuser.v94/HW5';
```